# how can i iterate over items in two different arrays in awk?

Tags: awk

I want to do something like:

```
for (x in {a,b}) {
  ...
}
```

Is there a way to do this in awk?

Comment: This question(http://stackoverflow.com/q/6541420/378509) tries to address the same. Please take a look at it.

Comment: Are they contiguously numerically indexed or are they sparse or associative?

Comment: @vk239: The poster of the question you linked to wanted to do indirection. That's not what allen wants.

Comment: `for (x in a) {}; for (x in b) {}`

Comment: not of equal length. some elements the same, some different. goal here is to iterate over elements of the union really.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two options:

1)

```
for (x in a)
   u[x]

for (x in b)
   u[x]

for (x in u)
   print "Union Index:",x
```

2)

```
for (x in a)
   print "Union Index:",x

for (x in b)
   if (!(x in a))
      print "Union Index:",x
```

and if you want something you can use succinctly in a for loop:

```
$ cat tst.awk
function indices(a,b,u, x,c)
{
   for (x in a) {
      u[++c] = x
   }

   for (x in b) {
      if (!(x in a)) {
         u[++c] = x
      }
   }

   return c
}

BEGIN {
   a[3]="foo"
   a[9]=3

   b[5]=7
   b[15]=45

   for (i=1; i<=indices(a,b,u); i++) {
      print u[i]
   }
}
$ awk -f tst.awk
9
3
5
15
```

Comment: i think #2 is closest to what i'm looking for, though i'm surprised there's not a simpler/syntactical answer

Comment: awk tends towards simplicity which implies minimalism. It provides syntax and functions for things that are hard to do otherwise, but doesn't provide builtin functionality for things that are easy to do. In this case it's trivial to do with existing constructs (and not a common application) so it wouldn't make sense to clutter up the language with constructs specifically for this job.